# How to add a custom texture image for particle system in 8th wall?

Tags: augmented-reality, particle-system, webxr, 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I am working on 8th wall particle system (https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/fireworks-aframe) and I want to add a custom texture instead of the default 'star2.png'. I created an 'images' folder under assets and tried to reference it but it is not working.

Any help/ suggestions for the above would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "texture" parameter to your "particle-system" component in the rocket.js file and wrap the relative path to your asset inside a require()

Using https://www.8thwall.com/8thwall/fireworks-aframe/master/rocket.js#L41 as an example:

```js
rocketParticles.setAttribute('particle-system', {
  texture: require('./assets/images/myfile.png'),
  // rest of the params go here
})
```